# Force rendering of already computed reactive elements

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a shiny app that outputs several results through different render* functions.

The problem is that one of those results takes some time to compute. So I would like shiny to render the quick results as soon as possible.

Here is some code to illustrate

```
# ui.R
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    textOutput("res1"),
    textOutput('res2')
))

# server.R
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$res1 = renderText({
        "shows up instantly"
    })

    output$res2 = renderText({
            Sys.sleep(3)
            "shows up after 3 sec"
    })
})
```

For now, the webpage stays empty for 3 seconds and the two elements are rendered at once.

My question is the following one: is it possible to enforce that `output$res1` executes before `output$res2` and that it sends its results to the browser before the long computation begins ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround. The idea is to force all `render*` functions to send their results to the browser once before launching the long computations.

In the following code, the two text zones appear immediately and the second one is updated after 3 seconds.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

    status=reactiveValues(res1IsDone=FALSE,res2HasRendered=FALSE)

    output$res1 = renderText({
        status$res1IsDone = TRUE
        "shows up instantly"
    })

    output$res2 = renderText({
        if(isolate(!status$res1IsDone || !status$res2HasRendered)) {
            status$res2HasRendered = TRUE
            invalidateLater(100,session)
            "wait"
        } else {
            Sys.sleep(3)
            "shows up after 3 sec"

        }
    })
})
```

To my understanding, shiny is monothreaded and the results are sent back to the browser once all the `render*` functions are executed once (or when all invalidation are resolved ?).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [invalidateLater](https://gist.github.com/trestletech/8608815) otherwise if you only want to render text you can send text directly to the client using:

```
# ui.R
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      HTML("
            Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler ('print',function (message) {
              $('#'+message.selector).html(message.html);
              console.log(message);
            });
           ")
    )
  ),
  textOutput("res1"),
  textOutput('res2')
))

# server.R
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'print', message = list(selector = 'res1', html = "shows up instantly"))
  Sys.sleep(3)
  session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'print', message = list(selector = 'res2', html = "shows up after 3 sec"))
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Yet, it doen't solve my problems for more complex outputs.